# Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs connections reset

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

i have been building [App Engine Java Endpoints Module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints)

my sdk is 23 and my backend is online i checked it with my ID but i got this err

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: Connection reset
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did it fix it but

the error disappeared after making a localhost

even after i stopped the local host